# Optimising concurrency solution for Select-then-update pattern using WITH (READPAST, ROWLOCK, XLOCK)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, concurrency, locking

Assume I need to write a ticket sales system. A number of tickets are put in the pool for sale. When an order is placed I update the ticket record to mark that the ticket is bound to the order. The ticket-order relationship table is as follow. 3 tickets are put in the pool for testing.

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'Demo_TicketOrder', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [Demo_TicketOrder];
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Demo_TicketOrder] (
  [TicketId] int NOT NULL,
  [OrderId] int NULL
    INDEX IX_OrderId_TicketId (OrderId, TicketId),
);
INSERT INTO Demo_TicketOrder VALUES (1, NULL)
INSERT INTO Demo_TicketOrder VALUES (2, NULL)
INSERT INTO Demo_TicketOrder VALUES (3, NULL)
SELECT * FROM Demo_TicketOrder
```

Below is the script I wrote that will be invoked by an ASP.NET app. The @OrderId will be passed as parameter form the App. For testing purpose I hard-coded it to 1. I have another window opened with @OrderId set as 2. Now I can simulate the concurrency of 2 requests..

```
DECLARE @OrderId AS INT = 1

BEGIN TRANSACTION PlaceOrder
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @ticketId AS INT;
        SELECT TOP 1 @ticketId = TicketId FROM Demo_TicketOrder WITH (READPAST, ROWLOCK, XLOCK) WHERE [OrderId] is NULL ORDER BY TicketId;
        IF @@ROWCOUNT != 1 THROW 50001, 'No tickets left!', 1;

        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:5'; -- Simulate some delay that incurrs concurrent requests
        UPDATE Demo_TicketOrder WITH (ROWLOCK) SET [OrderId] = @OrderId WHERE [OrderId] IS NULL AND [TicketId] = @ticketId AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Demo_TicketOrder WHERE OrderId = @OrderId );
        IF @@ROWCOUNT != 1
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @ErrorMessage AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = CONCAT('Optimistic lock activated! TicketId=', CAST(@ticketId AS VARCHAR(20)));
            THROW 50002, @ErrorMessage, 2;
        END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION PlaceOrder;
        THROW
    END CATCH;      
COMMIT TRANSACTION PlaceOrder;
SELECT * FROM Demo_TicketOrder WHERE [TicketId] = @ticketId;
```

My target is for this piece of code to

1. Handle concurrent requests efficiently
   That's why I can't just simply do `SELECT` then `UPDATE WHERE OrderId IS NULL` because a lot of requests will fail when request volume boosts.
2. Do not allow two orders to be bound to one ticket.
   By using ROWLOCK, XLOCK in the SELECT I assume every requests will get an empty ticket. Also there's still an optimistic compare-and-update mechanism in the UPDATE statement as a safety net should the lock fails.
3. While a request is processing, do not block new coming requests.
   By using `READPAST` I expect all new requests will get the next available ticket immediately without waiting for 1st request to finish COMMIT.
4. In the off chance that two requests with the same OrderId comes, make sure only one is served
   By the `NOT EXISTS` condition of the UPDATE statement I assume this done.

**Why ask this question:**
I came up with this solution with my own because I did not find a mature pattern after extensive searching. But I think this kind of problem is quite common which got me worried that I may be over-complicating things or having left something unconsidered, as I'm new to T-SQL (always been using EF6). What worries me more is I never even see XLOCK being used online except for suggestions against it. Days has went into testing this piece of code and so far it seems OK but I just want to make sure.

QUESTION A.
Does this code cover my targets? Could it be simplified (without using queueing middle ware on the app level - that'd be another thing)?

QUESTION B.
While testing I found compound index `INDEX IX_OrderId_TicketId (OrderId, TicketId)` to be necessary. I can't understand why if I leave out the OrderId (having only IX_TicketId), I'll - 100% replicable - get a deadlock on the second request.

Comment: Hi I facing the same problem. what kind of Snapshot Isolation in your case ?

Comment: @TaiwanHotDog I endup using CTE as suggested by Dan's answer. I execute the CTE in a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand from C# code and did not set the isolation level anywhere. So I assumed it should be the READ COMMITTED by default. I conducted a bit of pressure test and it good enough. 2000 transactions in ~7 seconds IIRC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me this is unduly complex for the need. Consider a unique filtered index on `OrderId` to ensure the order is assigned to only 1 ticket. I expect a default pessimistic concurrency technique would provide adequate throughput (> 1K per second) without resorting to `READPAST`:

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'Demo_TicketOrder', N'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [Demo_TicketOrder];
CREATE TABLE dbo.Demo_TicketOrder (
      TicketId int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_Demo_TicketOrder PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
    , OrderId int NULL
);
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX Demo_TicketOrder_OrderId ON Demo_TicketOrder(OrderId);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Demo_TicketOrder_OrderId_NotNull ON Demo_TicketOrder(OrderId) WHERE OrderId IS NOT NULL;
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.usp_UpdateTicket
    @OrderID int
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
UPDATE TOP(1) dbo.Demo_TicketOrder
SET OrderId = @OrderId
WHERE OrderID IS NULL;
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 THROW 50001, 'No tickets left!', 1;
GO
```

Regarding the deadlock without `OrderId` as the first column, the subquery in the `UPDATE` is by `OrderId` so the table must be scanned without a supporting index. The scan is blocked when it encounters the row locked by the other session. The other session is similarly blocked when it tries to execute the update, resulting in the deadlock.

**EDIT:**

The order of assigned tickets is undefined with the above `UPDATE TOP(1)` method. There is no provision for `ORDER BY` with this syntax but that doesn't matter if the tickets are homogeneous.

If you have a requirement to assign orders to tickets in `TicketId` sequence, you could use a CTE or similar technique along with an `UPDLOCK` hint (to avoid deadlocking) and add `TicketId` to the clustered index key (to efficiently find the lowest unassigned `TicketId`.

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_Demo_TicketOrder_OrderId_TicketId ON Demo_TicketOrder(OrderId, TicketId);
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.usp_UpdateTicketV2
    @OrderID int
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
WITH next_available_ticket AS (
    SELECT TOP(1)
          TicketID
        , OrderId
    FROM dbo.Demo_TicketOrder AS t WITH(UPDLOCK)
    WHERE t.OrderId IS NULL
    ORDER BY t.TicketId
    )
UPDATE next_available_ticket
SET OrderId = @OrderId;
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 THROW 50001, 'No tickets left!', 1;
GO
```

Comment: Your one-line UPDATE is powerful and elegant. And the conditional UNIQUE is a good idea. I'm a bit curious since you cannot specify `ORDER BY` on this query, in what order will the tickets be used? Is it possible to ensure tickets with smaller ID used first? Like `UPDATE dbo.Demo_TicketOrder
SET OrderId = @OrderId
OUTPUT INSERTED.*
WHERE TicketId IN (SELECT TOP 1 TicketId FROM dbo.Demo_TicketOrder WHERE OrderID IS NULL ORDER BY TicketId ASC)` will it work? And what is the consideration to use `OrderId` instead of `TicketId` as a clustered index?

Comment: @LionetChen, I updated my answer with `ORDER BY` details. The reason for the `OrderID` clustered index is that is most optimal for the update and other queries by that column. `TicketId` could be a better choice depending on your query mix but the intent here is was to specifically optimize the `UPDATE`. Indexing strategies often involve trade-offs as one can have only one clustered index per table.

Comment: thanks for the update. Could you enlighten me on your choice of CTE over my Update-where-subquery method which although works in my testing but I’m sure you have your reasons. Is it because the way I write it Update and select are two statements and 2 almost concurrent requests may both select the same ticket before any of them updates? If this is the concern then in my understanding, Updlock can’t stop it either because it doesn’t prevent multiple reads.

Comment: @LionetChen, the CTE plan looks slightly better with basically seek-->top-->update. With the subquery, scan-->top-->seek-->update. An `UPDLOCK` hint on the subquery will serialize getting the next ticket and avoid the potential for attempting to assign the same order to different tickets.